# ecommerce Android/iOS app with free source code

Tags: android, ios

I own a small shop for clothes and and want to take it to Mobile platform. Is there any app available on Android Platform which offers free source code. I have a small team of IT guys who can manage there after.

Requirements:

- Android/iOS native app
- Free
- Source code can be modified and not redistributed, so public domain or similar
- Requiring some level of IT skills is OK

Comment: hey, what do you want EXACTLY? Do you want native apps for iOS and Android or do you want a webpage optimized for mobile devices?

Comment: Seeing asker's nickname "mobileapp", I guess they are looking for a mobile app. I modify the question on this premise.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas for editing. Thats what I need exactly.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try [MobStac](http://developer.mobstac.com/) Once you sign up you will be able to download and install the iOS SDK into your Xcode project.

Our Magento extension lets you import catalog information from your e-commerce backend and once done, your iOS app is ready! Check it out.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! This post does not contain enough information to be considered a high quality answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/107) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer. Going over the requirements identified in the answer would be much better than requiring interested people to click the link and possibly read multiple pages of docs to figure out that.